# Статистика запуска одной программы из консоли

Tags: bash, phpunit, zsh

Я работаю из консоли, периодически запуская одну и ту же программу. Ее название не принципиально для вопроса, но для простоты изложения - это `phpunit`.

Задался вопросом, а сколько раз за день я запускаю ее? Наверное, сотни, но это не точно. А сколько времени в сумме заняло ее выполнение?

Есть ли какая-то вспомогательная программа, с которой можно сделать так: назначить алиас `alias phpunit='write_metrics phpunit'`, который будет вести журнал, а потом `read_metrics dayly`, который выведет статистику:

```
количество запусков: 100
общее время выполнения: 1 час
```

Как это можно посчитать? Писать что-то свое не хочется, наверняка есть готовое.

Comment: **alias phpunit='/usr/bin/time  -f "%E" /usr/bin/phpunit 2>>/var/log/phpunit_statistics.log'**. А для другого алиаса статистики - число запусков (количество строк) и среднего времени (суммарное время, деленное на число запусков) -  можно и простой скрипт накидать, работающий с текстовым лог-файлом

Comment: А нет каких-то готовых решений? Скрипт написать можно, но зачем, если есть готовое

Comment: Конечно же есть: на SO хватает [примеров](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642013/)

Comment: Если бы стояла задача аналитики приложения: дебаггинг, тестирование, - то конечно же, имело бы смысл установить инструмент профилирования **Linux perf**. Но для текущей задачи, мне кажется, это - как из пушки по воробьям.